# htaccess remove index.php? from url

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I need to remove index.php? from URL.

From: `https://example.com/index.php?/discover/`

To: `https://forum.fibaro.com/discover/`

I tried everything, but doesn't work :/

Comment: Whatever you tried put it in question.

Comment: but it does not work, so why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were trying to mach against URI only so, let me explain something here :

```
https://example.com/index.php?/discover/
```

This part `index.php` is URI , then there is `?` and after that is `/discover/` , the last part is query string so to match against it you could use `QUERY_STRING or THE_REQUEST` Server-Variables according to what you need but when using `REQUEST_URI` you match only against URI part.

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,7}\s/index\.php\?\/(.*)\sHTTP.*$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$  /%1? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule !^index\.php$  /index.php?%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

The code above will redirect `https://example.com/index.php?/discover/` to `https://example.com/discover/` externally and then redirect it again to same path .

**Note:** clear browser cache then test it .